# Sort a file to put 10, 11, 12... before 1, 2, 3... and X,Y

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a list of chromosome data with the columns (chromosome, start, and end) like this:

```
chr1    6252071 6253740
chr1    6965107 6966070
chr1    6966038 6967016
chr1    7066595 7068694
chr1    7100956 7102296
chr1    7153422 7154635
chr1    7155112 7156181
....
chr2
....
chr10
....
chrX
....
chrY
....
```

etc.

I am trying to use bash to sort the chromosome sections to this order:

```
chr10
chr11
chr12
chr13
chr14
chr15
chr16
chr17
chr18
chr19
chr1
chr2
chr3
chr4
chr5
chr6
chr7
chr8
chr9
chrM
chrX
chrY
```

in the first column, and then in numerical order by start position in the second column, but no variation of `sort` seems to do the job. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the intended logic in a manner other than by example? If you want to take a section, and -- despite correct sort order putting them in the middle -- move it to the top, well, you can do that by splitting and recombining the streams, but it's hardly a sort operation as such.

Answer (score 1):

Split your file into two streams with separate filtering, then recombine them:

```
cat <(grep    '^chr1[[:digit:]][[:space:]]' <inputfile | sort) \
    <(grep -v '^chr1[[:digit:]][[:space:]]' <inputfile | sort) \
    >outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -E '
  open $f, "<", shift; 
  say join "", 
      map {$_->[0]}
      sort {length($b->[1]) <=> length($a->[1]) or $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]} 
      map {[$_, (split)[0]]}
      <$f>
' file
```

It first `open`s the file.
Then it uses a Schwartzian Transform: read the next command from the bottom up:

1. read the lines:  `<$f>`
2. transform the lines to a list of pairs: the original line, and the first word:
   `map {[$_, (split)[0]}`
3. sort, first by length (longest to shortest), then lexically (A to Z)
4. transform the list of pairs to a list of lines (the first element of the pair)
   `map {$_->[0]}`
5. join (the lines still have their newlines, so join on the empty string